# How to close all dialogs modal opened using angular-material at once

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

I'm using angular material [dialogcomponent](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) in my angular app to open a dialog box whenever an error comes from the server.

If multiple error comes at time  it opens multiple dialog boxes that's fine for me.I want close all dialog boxes at once using `closeAll` method.

When try to use `closeAll` method getting this error:

```js
error TS2339: Property 'closeAll' does not exist on type 'MatDialogRef<DialogComponent, any>'.
```

**How I'm opening the dialog:**

```js
 constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
          width: "500px",
          height: "500px",
          disableClose: true,
          hasBackdrop: true,
          data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
        });
```

DialogComponent.ts

```js
onClose(): void {
    this.dialogRef.closeAll();
  }
```

app.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DialogComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
      ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [ DialogComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Inject MatDialog to the DialogComponent.ts**

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

export class DialogComponent  {
  constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog) { }

  public onClose(): void {
    this._dialog.closeAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject `MatDialog` to the `DialogComponent.ts`

```js
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }
```

```js
 onClose(): void {
    this.dialog.closeAll();
  }
```